# javascript - declaration of local variable

Tags: javascript

i am using the following javascript code.. i've declared local variables before the starting of all the functions but functions donot execute when called.. but when i replace all of the variables in the function with their content only then it works... what could i be doing wrong.. my code is as follows...

```
/* variables */
    var dmv = document.getElementById("dmv").style;
    var nomv = document.getElementById("nomv").style;
    var frsv = document.getElementById("frsv").style;
/* end of variables */

function messagesClick() {
    document.getElementById("notifications").style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (dmv.visibility == 'hidden') {
        dmv.visibility = 'visible';
        nomv.visibility = 'hidden';
        frsv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
            dmv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function notificationsClick() {
    document.getElementById("notifications").style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (nomv.visibility == 'hidden') {
        nomv.visibility = 'visible';
        dmv.visibility = 'hidden';
        frsv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
            nomv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function friendRequestClick() {
    document.getElementById("notifications").style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (frsv.visibility == 'hidden') {
        frsv.visibility = 'visible';
        dmv.visibility = 'hidden';
        nomv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
            frsv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Are you trying to access the DOM before it's fully loaded?

Comment: Here is a discussion about how to check if document is ready without jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: For the guy who voted negative: aren't we supposed to explain why the negative vote? If you think that the question is "bad" you are supposed to explain why so new users can improve their questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the elements exist before you can access them.

You can wait until you need the values the first time to get them:

```
var dmv, nomv, frsv;
var gotStyles = false;

function getStyles() {
    if (!gotStyles) {
        gotStyles = true;
        dmv = document.getElementById("dmv").style;
        nomv = document.getElementById("nomv").style;
        frsv = document.getElementById("frsv").style;
    }
}

function messagesClick() {
    getStyles();
    document.getElementById("notifications").style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (dmv.visibility == 'hidden') {
        dmv.visibility = 'visible';
        nomv.visibility = 'hidden';
        frsv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
            dmv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function notificationsClick() {
    getStyles();
    document.getElementById("notifications").style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (nomv.visibility == 'hidden') {
        nomv.visibility = 'visible';
        dmv.visibility = 'hidden';
        frsv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
            nomv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function friendRequestClick() {
    getStyles();
    document.getElementById("notifications").style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (frsv.visibility == 'hidden') {
        frsv.visibility = 'visible';
        dmv.visibility = 'hidden';
        nomv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
            frsv.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```